# Jersey - 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: java, rest, jersey, http-status-code-405

I'm new with Web Services. I have a working endpoint which returns me a JSON with the person data, if the parameters (identifier and password) are informed correctly.

Like this:

```
http://www.issdigitalthe.com.br/controleacesso/servico/api/login/4/SMT/000000000000/password/false
```

Where 000000000000 is my identifier, and "password" is my password.

Testing with PostMan (POST), this is my return:

```
"id": 40001002131,
    "idOriginal": 123131,
    "cpfCnpj": "000000000",
    "nome": "JOHN DOE",
    "idCargo": 131313131,
    "descricaoCargo": "Usuário responsável por analisar e Deferir/Indeferir os Protocolos.",
    "idDepartamento": 4000200000000761,
    "descricaoDepartamento": "Departamento para usuários ",
    "login": "000000000",
    "email": "john@gmail.com",
    "ultimoAcesso": 1537824078846,
    "certificadoDigital": "N",
    "dataCriacao": null,
    "bairro": "Bairro",
    "cep": "64020340",
    "complemento": "Quadra 00 Casa 111",
    "dddCelular": "86 ",
    "dddTelefone": "86 ",
    "celular": "99999999",
    "telefone": "86 ",
    "uf": "PI",
    "municipio": "SÃO PAULO",
```

I have to consume that service to check if the return is valid or not. 
Here's my code:

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;

@Path("/")
@ManagedBean
public class WebServiceLoginMB {

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + MediaType.TEXT_HTML)

    public String getDados() {
        Client c = Client.create();
        WebResource wr = c.resource("//www.issdigitalthe.com.br/controleacesso/servico/api/login/4/SMT/000000000000/password/false);
        return wr.get(String.class); 
      }
}
```

At first, i was just trying to see the return on my Glassfish console, and then i would check if the return is correct or not. But i'm always getting
"returned a response status of 405 Method Not Allowed".

It worked like this:

```
    public static void ws(String user, String pass) {

        try {

            Client client = Client.create();
            WebResource webResource = client.resource(
"http://www.issdigitalthe.com.br/controleacesso/servico/api/login/4/SMT/"+ user + "/"+ pass + "/false");
            ClientResponse response = webResource.type("application/json").post(ClientResponse.class);

            String output = response.getEntity(String.class);
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            PessoaNota pessoa = gson.fromJson(output, PessoaNota.class);
            System.out.println(pessoa.getNome());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I know it still got some things to adjust, but the first problem was solved. Thanks to everyone who helped.

Comment: Do I get that right? You want to make the user name and password part of the url? If so: very bad idea.

Comment: jax-rs and jsf are never related. Sure it works if you remove the `@ManageBean`? And it is btw not good practice to make a jax-rs class also a jsf managed bean.

Comment: Jsf tag removed. Can you elaborate on the good practice? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because you are performing HTTP GET call, while in postman you tried HTTP POST. Try to make a post call like this

```
public String getDados() {
    Client c = Client.create();
    WebResource wr = c.resource("http://www.issdigitalthe.com.br/controleacesso/servico/api/login/4/SMT/000000000000/password/false);
    return wr.post(String.class); 
  }
```

Comment: I changed, but i still get the same error.  "com.sun.jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException:GET http://www.issdigitalthe.com.br/controleacesso/servico/api/login/4/SMT/00000000/password /false returned a response status of 405 Method Not Allowed"

Comment: also http is missing in resource, please check updated code

Comment: On mine i used http, same result